# Swift MacOS Set Mouse Cursor Position

Tags: swift, macos

I'm beginner about Swift. ( I have no experience about objective-c)

I'm having trouble about the mouse cursor position.

I want to change the cursor position globally when I click the left mouse button.( Not only in my app's view)
For example, When app detect the mouse click, change the mouse position to specific Point(x, y)

Currently, I can detect the left mouse click.
So, When that event occurs, only the coordinates need to be changed.

So, I found the reference.

In the developer document, CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(_:) will be helpful to me.
But, I have no idea how to use it.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456387-cgwarpmousecursorposition

```
NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .leftMouseDown, handler: change) as! NSObject

func change(_event : NSEvent){ // In Here I want to change the mouse position }
```

Any advice or documentation to refer to would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can change the `NSEvent` you're given, but you don't need to. Once you've detected the condition that you want to cause the mouse to move, you can juist call `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(_:)`. It just takes the destination coordinates, in the form of a [`CGPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpoint).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I think so too. But, I do not have a understanding of swift.   In order to use the function, what do I need to import or delegate?  Because, can't find the function when just use it. I know it's stupid question. Sorry. If possible, Could you give me addtional advise?

Comment: Looking at the top of [the documentation for `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456387-cgwarpmousecursorposition), you can see it's in the `CoreGraphics` framework. So in the file where you want to use it, you'll need to `import CoreGraphics`

Comment: Ok, thank you for helping me. I need to see the documentation. Have nice day :)

Comment: Always start with the documentation. They don't just write it because it's fun for them :p